# Is there a way to pass regex to string option in minimist?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to interpret some of my commandline arguments (using [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist)) as string instead of int. Minimist provides and option to pass an array of commandline arguments you wish to consider as strings.

Something like this:

```
var args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  "string": [ "abc-src" ] 
});
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
var args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  "string": [ /^*-src/ ] 
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unknown` option to parse the arguments:

```
const minimist = require('minimist');

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  "unknown": (arg) => { /^.*-src$/.test(arg) }
});

console.log(args);
```

With the following:

```
node index --foo-src=bar --bar-src=foo
```

It returns the following:

```
{ _: [], 'foo-src': 'bar', 'bar-src': 'foo' }
```

Hope that helps